# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting based on value of cell in another sheet - Custom Formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

How can I achieve the following:

- **Sheet1:** has a range of cells A1:M13 which have conditional format rules: if text is exactly "1" (to "15" so 15 rules) → each number gives the cell a different background filling.
- **Sheet2:** I want do Conditional Formatting on range A1:M13 based on the cell values in Sheet1!A1:M13.

At the moment I have the following custom formula in conditional formatting:

```
=if((INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:M13=1")))
```

What do I do wrong? Do I have to set format of Sheet1 to value=1 instead of text is exactly "1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this to range `A1:M13` in `Sheet2` for cell to cell comparison:

```
=1=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&CELL("address",A1))
```

[image]

Comment: "Invalid formula".

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah try instead of ',' ';'

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A1)=1
```

or

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A1)="1"
```

Comment: The formula is not invalid, but does not works...

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?